# How to get the cursor position within a centered div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was making a drawing app and I had to center it.

To detect the cursor position I used

```
$('#drawbox').mousedown(function(e){
    paint = true;

    var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    addClick(e.pageX-this.offsetLeft, e.pageY-this.offsetTop);
    redraw();
});
```

the drawbox div is wrapped in a centering div with the following style

```
position:relative;
margin:auto;
text=align:center;
```

It resulted in my drawings being out of bounds, for some reasons it was working fine without the centering wrapper div. thanks you for your help

Here is a fiddle for demo

https://jsfiddle.net/ok0ohbxj/

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt show the problem. Do you want it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/nvfkqh2h/ ? (Didn't change something, just included jQuery and wrapped the canvas around a div with your specified class). Works for me.

Comment: @lexith yes that's exactly what I want, thanks! For some strange reasons the exact same code didn't work on my testing environment. My drawings were clustered at the bottom right of the canvas and would sometimes not display them either

Comment: @lexith I have updated the jsfiddle to show you what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/nvfkqh2h/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering to the fiddle you posted in a comment to your question, the problem is your usage of `offsetTop`:

> The HTMLElement.offsetTop read-only property returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node.

In your case, the offsetParent node is the wrapping container `.centerHelper` not your document.

Since you're already using jQuery, i suggest to go with `$('drawbox').offset()` instead, which returns the offset relative to the document:

```
$('#drawbox').mousedown(function(e){
    paint = true;

    var mouseX = e.pageX - $('#drawbox').offset().left;
    var mouseY = e.pageY - $('#drawbox').offset().top;
    addClick(mouseX, mouseY);
    redraw();
});

$('#drawbox').mousemove(function(e){
    if (paint){
        var mouseX = e.pageX - $('#drawbox').offset().left;
        var mouseY = e.pageY - $('#drawbox').offset().top;
        addClick(mouseX,mouseY, true);
        redraw();
    }
});
```

And a fiddle for you to try out: https://jsfiddle.net/6gwnexjL/